# How do I get a shape to stop when it reaches another shape (Android)?

Tags: android, animation, sprite, geometry

I'm just playing around with basic animation on the Android platform. What I have so far allows the user to touch the screen and a circle, centered at the touch, will increase its radius until the user lifts his finger or the circle hits the edge of the screen. I have a class set up to store the center and radius of each circle so that every circle is drawn to the screen. What is the best way to make a circle stop increasing its radius when it hits another circle?

Comment: Do your research first and then ask the question if you can't find anything to help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me google that for you

http://badasshat.blogspot.com/2010/03/2d-collision-detection-part-1.html